# Ag-Grid : Cannot read property 'api' of undefined

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I am using custom pagination control. To initialize the control I am calling gridOptions.api.paginationGetPageSize() and gridOptions.api.paginationGetRowCount(). I tried calling the two api methods on **onPaginationChanged** and **onGridReady**, everytime I get the error

> Cannot read property 'api' of undefined

Any ideas why. I am using md-paginator (angular material 2 control) for paging.

Comment: My ag-grid is located inside child component, as I am using tabs (tabs are the child components.). How do I know if child component is initialized?

Answer (score -1):

One possibility is that your view cannot find and initialize your grid in the component.

Have you tried the following:

```
<ag-grid-angular *ngIf="gridOptions != null" ...
```